# Adding an Angular 6 project into Autodesk.viewer a BufferGeometry with color or texture or heat map

Tags: three.js, angular6, autodesk-forge

I am creating a project in Angular 6 in which I visualized an ifc file preloaded with Authdesk.

I can visualize the 3d model and I would like to ask for help and examples in angular to duplicate a clicked element and apply a heatmap on it.

I found some examples online but they date back to old versions not in Angular.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See a code sample [here](https://github.com/jeremytammik/forgefader) and an extension [here](https://github.com/apprentice3d/SD226781-Samples/blob/master/extensions/HeatExt.js) for implementing heatmaps with Forge Viewer:
**[image: strong text]**

Also see a youtube video on this topic [here](https://youtu.be/78JlGnf49mc).

However there's unfortunately limited Angular resources with Forge - I'd recommend to check out our friend Alan's wrapper for Viewer [here](https://github.com/theNBS/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer) but keep in my mind that's not maintained officially by Autodesk and might not be up to date with the latest Viewer.